# Migrated from 32 bit to 64 bit and getting unrelated sqlcode while dealing with Oracle DB

Tags: c++, oracle10g

Previously we had 32 bit C++. Now, we have migrated it to 64 bit. And our C++ programs interact with Oracle 10g DB.

Our C++ program was working fine with 32 bit. But once after we migrate to 64 bit we are facing problem with one program which does:

> FETCH(EXEC SQL FETCH SUBP1 INTO :newTabRec;)

from Oracle DB.

We exit from a for loop in the C++ program when we get:

> NOT FOUND(sqlca.sqlcode=1403)

on executing the FETCH statement.

The sqlcode generated for NOT FOUND scenario is `1403`. But, once after moving to 64 bit C++, we do not see the sqlcode `1403` instead we are seeing a different code `7124089117159473`.

As the sqlcode is not `1403`, our program does not exit from the for loop and goes on an infinite loop.

Am I missing anything that makes me to not get the exact sqlcode?

Comment: It got fixed. The variables sqlabc, sqlcode and sqlerrd in the header file sqlca.h were long previously. After changing all these to int, it started working.